# How to run file .exe by air?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

this is my cod:

```
  var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();

  var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("android.exe");
  nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
  var myAppProcess = new NativeProcess();
  myAppProcess.start(file);
```

It does not work.

please help me
thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run file .exe by air as3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226890/how-to-run-file-exe-by-air-as3)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if NativeProcess is supported?

```
if(NativeProcess.isSupported)
    setupAndLaunch();
else
    trace("NativeProcess not supported.");
```

The NativeProcess class and its capabilities are only available to AIR applications installed with a native installer (extended desktop profile applications). When debugging, you can pass the -profile extendedDesktop argument to ADL to enable the NativeProcess functionality. At runtime, you can check the NativeProcess.isSupported property to to determine whether native process communication is supported.